# Views show list of nodes that have referenced node on another content type

Tags: views

I have research and people content types.
In people content type I have nodes that are authors for researches.
I referenced author name field on research content type to people content type.
Now I want to show all people type nodes that referenced in research content type nodes.
In another word I want to show list of all my authors from my people content type.
Thank you very mach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Add view from people content type.
2. and add relationship referencing entity with the author_name field and check Require this relationship.
3. To remove repeated rows use [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module.